# How do I define the guild I want to use ".channels" on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm setting up a bot analytics staff channel for my discord bot's support server.
I want the bot to be able to send a message and then edit it every minute. But, when I try to do this, I get an error saying that I didn't define the guild that I want to use `.channels` on. The exact error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined.`

I've tried defining my guild in many different ways, including making it into a variable and combining it with the function that finds the guild itself. But, none of these possible solutions, some of which coming from some related Stack Overflow posts, have worked for me.
I've also tried looking at some tutorials, but they also haven't worked either: the code always says that I'm not defining my guild correctly.

```
//Stats For Staff Channel
let serverchannel = bot.guilds.get("498548588318556210").channels.get("528288924917825556");
let servercount = bots.guilds.size
let uptimetotalseconds = (bot.uptime / 1000);
let uptimehours = Math.floor(uptimetotalseconds / 360);
uptimeseconds %= 3600;
let uptimeminutes = Math.floor(uptimetotalseconds / 60);
let uptimeseconds = uptimetotalseconds % 60;
let uptime = "Total Uptime: \n \n Hours: " + uptimehours + "\n Minutes: " + uptimeminutes + "\n Seconds: " + uptimeseconds + "\n Total Uptime In Seconds: " + uptimetotalseconds + "\n Total Uptime In MiliSeconds " + bot.upTime + "\n \n \n \n"
let messagetobesent = "**Bot Status** \n \n" + "Server Count: **" + servercount + " guilds** \n \n" + "Total Uptime: \n Hours: **" + uptimehours + "** \n" + "Minutes: **" + uptimeminutes + "** \n \n **Thats it!These stats are updated every minute and more are being added soon. ** "
serverchannel.send(messagetobesent)
while (true) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    message.edit(messagetobesent)
  }, 60000);
}
```

The bot should grab the support server and channel that I want the message to be sent to by using their ids. Then, it should send a message stored as a variable in that channel. Finally, every minute it will edit that message with the new value of the variable.

Comment: Why do you have a timeout inside an infinite loop?

Comment: To wait before continuing, do these not work that way? Sorry, I am still fairly new to javascript.

Comment: Timeouts in Javascript don't block execution the way pausing/sleeping does in some other languages. Using it in a `while(true)` loop will create infinite timers. You should use setInterval instead.

Comment: Oh ok. I still need to figure out how to fix the undefined error though somehow so hopefully someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: You're getting the channel in the right way, the only thing you can do is to check the ID: you can get your guild id by enabling developer mode in Discord and right-clicking your guild's icon, then click "Copy ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined.
```

This error actually means that it couldn't find the guild you're trying to get, Are you sure that `bot.guilds.get("498548588318556210")` actually returns a guild? Maybe `bot` is defined by another Discord.js client inside your code that's not in the guild you're trying to get? Or is there actually a guild with that ID? Or is your client actually a member of that guild?

Comment: Just checked the ID, it is correct. Bot is `const bot = new discord.Client();`. And, it does exist and the bot is in it.

Comment: Fixed it, used some of your advice but removed the guild part because I didn't need it. Thanks!